# How can I play Majesty (natively) on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-center, games

[Majesty: The Fantasy Kingdom Sim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majesty:_The_Fantasy_Kingdom_Sim) is one of my favorite games. It was released in 2000 for Windows and Mac, and Linux Game Publishing released a version that ran natively on Linux in 2003.

- For awhile, this game was available in the Ubuntu Software Center, sitting at [the #10 spot in top paid applications](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Top-10-Paid-Apps-on-Ubuntu-Software-Center-for-September-297322.shtml) several years ago. It doesn't appear to be available there anymore
- The game [was available through the independent Desura game store](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/945476-majesty-the-fantasy-kingdom-sim-gold-edition/data). I bought it there several years ago, and it worked fine for awhile, but when I reinstalled Ubuntu recently, I found out I can no longer install Desura as [they seem to have shut down](http://www.oneplay.com/en/news/details/244_Desura_is_now_a_part_of_the_OnePlay_family_). Content purchased there seems to be lost (at least for now).
- The [Linux Game Publishing website](http://www.linuxgamepublishing.com/back-soon) has been down for several years now, so no chance to buy it directly from the source.
- [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/25990/Majesty_Gold_HD/) and [GOG](https://www.gog.com/game/majesty_gold_hd) only have the Windows version of the game.

Is it still possible to buy and play the Linux port of this game?

Comment: GOG games usually run well under WINE.

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably give Wine a shot. The latest rating is Bronze, which is a little disappointing when I know a high quality Linux port exists, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: is the bronze rating for the GOG version or the original cd?  there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the release of [Proton](https://steamcommunity.com/games/221410/announcements/detail/1696055855739350561) late last year, I tried the [Steam version of Majesty Gold HD](https://store.steampowered.com/app/25990/Majesty_Gold_HD/), and it worked flawlessly, which [seems to be the consensus](https://www.protondb.com/app/25990).

Technically this is not "the Linux port" of Majesty, but it runs just as well (possibly better, because it's the "HD" version which handles higher resolutions and mouse sensitivity better than the original). This solution also requires purchasing an additional copy via Steam, even if you previously purchased the Linux port, but they regularly have it on sale for under $3.